# Named pipes and OVERLAPPED on Windows

Tags: winapi, named-pipes

I'm about to implement my first Windows service. The service will connect to a Bluetooth dongle, and liaison some commands and data to a single client process.
Each process (client, server), shall have at least two thread - one blocking on Read(), another crunching business logic and doing an occasionally Write().

Checking the alternatives, I've decided to go with [Named Pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx) for IPC, but I'm having trouble understanding some of the settings. Specifically:

- I wish to allow simultaneous reads and writes. Do I need to create the pipe with [`FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150(v=vs.85).aspx), even though I do not intend to do reads and writes on the same thread?
- If the answer to the above is 'yes', do I still need to pass an `OVERLAPPED` structure to [`ReadFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx), [`WriteFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx), use [`GetOverlappedResult()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683209(v=vs.85).aspx) etc? If so, what is the rational behind this?
- What is so great about having a single thread do non-blocking reads and writes anyway? What are the use cases?

**EDIT**

I wish to clarify the question:

- Assuming both threads (Read / Write) access the pipe simultaneously, will one block until the other is done due to some internal pipe mutex?
- Will setting `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` change this behavior?

Comment: A pipe already allows simultaneous reads and writes.  If you are going to use a thread for the reads then you just don't need overlapped I/O at all.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks. I guess what I wanted to ask was: "If one thread reads, and another writes at the same time, will one block until the other is done?" - fixing the question

Comment: @bavaza: Distinct threads can read and write simultaneously, without interfering with each other. This is true regardless of whether you use asynchronous (overlapped) I/O or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED if all you're doing is reading and writing using the same handle at the same time. Other threads reading or writing to the same end of the pipe won't cause it to block. You only need it if you want to perform asynchronous I/O, which apparently you don't.

If you do use the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED you must pass a valid OVERLAPPED structure to ReadFile and WriteFile via the lpOverlapped argument. If you don't use this flag and the handle isn't seekable (eg. a named pipe) then you must pass NULL instead.

The big advantage of using single threaded asynchronous I/O over a multi-threaded implementation is that you don't have to worry about concurrency issues. You can't have race conditions and deadlocks if you only have one thread. (Actually in your case, since you would still have two threads, one in the server and one the client, you can still have deadlocks and maybe race conditions if you really try, but asynchronous I/O would still make it easier to avoid them.)

Comment: I do wish to do async I/O, but not from a single thread. Namely - I don't want the reading thread to block until the writing thread is done and vice versa.

Comment: @bavaza If you want the reading thread to block until there's something available to read on the handle then you wish to do synchronous I/O. As I said you don't need to use the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED flag if all you're doing is reading and writing from the same handle simultaneously. With synchronous I/O reads only block if there's nothing to read, and writes only if there's no room in the pipe's buffer to store the write. Other threads reading or writing to the same end of the pipe won't cause it to block.

Comment: "Other threads reading or writing to the same end of the pipe won't cause it to block" - this is what I was after, thanks. Can you add it to your answer?

Comment: Is it true that we don't need FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED to read and write to the same named pipe in a different thread? I was not able to accomplish this.

Comment: @Rick it isn't possible as per docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms810467(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#nonoverlapped-io  
I also tried it, didn't work... Threads were stuck.

Answer (score 2):

To enable bi-directional access to a pipe, you have to specify the [PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150.aspx) flag for the *dwOpenMode* parameter. [Asynchronous operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365788.aspx) (`FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`) is not strictly required to enable bi-directional mode.

Using asynchronous I/O, however, is recommended for bi-directional pipes. It allows you to issue both read and write operations at the same time, on the same thread (see [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx)). Either operation is signaled upon **completion**. This prevents a lengthy write operation from blocking a potential read, for example, and you'll be able to respond to either one in a timely manner. Maybe even more importantly, since you never know when data is available, you'll typically want to always issue a read operation, without having it block your thread.

This is outlined in the documentation for [CreateNamedPipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150.aspx):

> If [overlapped] mode is enabled, functions performing read, write, and connect operations that may take a significant time to be completed can return immediately. This mode enables the thread that started the operation to perform other operations while the time-consuming operation executes in the background. For example, in overlapped mode, a thread can handle simultaneous input and output (I/O) operations on multiple instances of a pipe or **perform simultaneous read and write operations on the same pipe handle**. If overlapped mode is not enabled, functions performing read, write, and connect operations on the pipe handle do not return until the operation is finished. The [**ReadFileEx**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468.aspx) and [**WriteFileEx**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365748.aspx) functions can only be used with a pipe handle in overlapped mode. The [**ReadFile**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx), [**WriteFile,**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747.aspx) [**ConnectNamedPipe**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365146.aspx), and [**TransactNamedPipe**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365790.aspx) functions can execute either synchronously or as overlapped operations.